# GridView Unbound Column Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with DevExpress, I inserted a gridview in a view (generated automatically with it's partial and stuff) and I want to add an unbound column in it.

```
@{
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        //configuration code and other columns
        settings.Columns.Add(c =>
        {
            c.FieldName = "ClientFinal";
            c.Caption = "Client Final";
            c.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
            c.UnboundExpression = "[Prenom] + ' ' + [Nom]";
        });
//configuration code
    });
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

ClientFinal entity:

```
public class ClientFinal : XPObject
    {
        public ClientFinal(Session session) : base(session) { }
        public override void AfterConstruction() { base.AfterConstruction(); }

        private string nom;
        public string Nom
        {
            get { return nom; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Nom", ref nom, value); }
        }

        private string prenom;
        public string Prenom
        {
            get { return prenom; }
            set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Prenom", ref prenom, value); }
        }
//other attributes
    }
```

Result:
[image]

I even tried : `c.UnboundExpression = "[ClientFinal.Prenom] + ' ' + [ClientFinal.Nom]";` but it didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: The code you demonstrated is absolute correct. Setting the grid column's FieldName property seems to be unnecessary, but it should not cause of the error. Hence, I believe that the mistake is in the code that you did not show.

Comment: The code in question was all shown (if I remove it it won't be any column with #Err) if there is any other code involved in the operation please tell me I will post it. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea which code might be a culprit. Error might be in your own code, as well as in the DevExpress libraries. All that I can say for sure is that your code is fine according to the official documentation. If I was you, I would check whether any CLR exception is thrown when openning a problematic page. The exception message might contain the information useful to understand its cause.

Comment: I tried debugging and adding breakpoints all over but no exception was thrown :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it, the problem was that the Unbound Column feature was not well explained in the devexpress documentation.
First:

```
c.FieldName = "ClientFinalUnbound";
```

The property FieldName has to be unique and it's just a name for the column not a mapping for the existing field in the entity in question (the one showed in the grid).

Second:

```
c.UnboundExpression = "[ClientFinal.Prenom] + ' ' + [ClientFinal.Nom]";
```

In the unbound expression the fields has to be existing ones (listed as properties in the entity definition or child elements of properties in the entity definition), so here I'm calling the Prenom (or Nom) property of the ClientFinal property in the RendezVous entity (the one showed in the grid).

Thanks